# Is the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 compatible with GA-870A?

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard, pci-express

I'm looking to buy a Wifi adaptor for my desktop, and came across this: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/centrino/centrino-advanced-n-6200-brief.html

It looks like what I want, but my concern is that it is a 'half form' PCIe card, and many not fit into the PCIe slots on my motherboard.

My question: Is this wifi card compatible (Out of the box) with this motherboard: GA-870A?

Thanks,
Steffan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Half* just refers to the height. It is the *Mini* you have to worry about.

Mini PCIe cards are for notebooks, not desktop computers.

A PCIe x1 slot has `11 + 7` connectors. By looking at the image, you can tell that the card will not fit.

Comment: Thanks! I have instead opted for a PCI card, that I know fits.